# Proper way to replicate Magento 2 Project from git

Tags: magento2, git

I have worked on some Magento 2 Projects, the main problem is when I pull every Magento 2 projects from git and load the project in the browser it always asks me to do the fresh installation, even after I configure the `app/etc/env.php` and the database properly

Comment: Have you copy working project env.php file ?

Comment: @NikunjVadariya yes

Comment: please confirm your env.php file permission is 664?

Comment: I am assuming that after you have it working you have checked to see what has changed in the project? i.e. git status?

Answer (score -4):

The issue is coming because it may be env.php has been committed in git repository. So, when ever you will doing git pull the local env.php is replace by remote env.php which is not compatible for local environment. So first delete the env.php from remote brunch and then put env.php in .gitignore file. Thus it will be ignore by git pull and push. In this way local env.php not replaced by remote env.php.

Comment: Have you understood his question properly?

Comment: Yes @Nikunj Vadariya , as per my understanding git setup was not done properly which causes the issue. That's why  I have given a tested process where everything working fine. Then what wrong with that.

Comment: He has issued only "project always asks to do the fresh installation".  I am pretty sure if he follows your steps only then issue will not resolve.

Comment: Has he told you that after following my step, the issue not resolved or you have tested my step. Then how did you pretty sure! ridiculous!.

Comment: @PrasantaHatui, do you know magento 2 ask installation if you have not added below parameter in your enav.php file?

`'install' => 
  array (
    'date' => 'Fri, 17 Nov 2017 06:19:19 +0000',
  ),`

Comment: Have read my answer?  there is step where magento setup will run and install i which step environment variable will create. Also have you checked my .gitignore file where this file is ignore by git. As a result when he will do git pull and git push this file will not updated and the above issue will never come. Stop doing comment with little knowledge.

Comment: Why are you not understanding, he has tried to configure `app/etc/env.php` the file still magento 2 asking for installation. it means his `app/etc/env.php` file not proper or magento 2 could not found `app/etc/env.php` file.  so, either that file needs proper permission or need to the proper parameters.

Comment: @PrasantaHatui, can you explain in detail, how your answer solves OP's problem

Comment: "when he pull every Magento 2 projects " please read this. it means when ever he does git pull that file is updated to the one that is commited in git. after that he has facing this issue. If this file is written in .gitignore the issue will resolved. So don't downvote this answer.

Comment: @PrasantaHatui He is fetching clean project from git and put his env.php then also he has probelm , now tell me how your answer solves his problem

Comment: @Murtuza Zabuawala , I have explained above commant.

Comment: put env.php in .gitignore will resolved the issue

Comment: Hi guys, I have modified my answer. if till not proper let me know.

Comment: @PrasantaHatui, bro he used word fresh installation, so how `env.php` is there in his git ?? and also he mentioned that he has modified env.php as per his need , so how this issue related to gitignor ??